# The option shorten (from nicematrix) does not seem to work for OverBrace command

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, nicematrix

I am trying to use the option `shorten` with `\OverBrace` and `\UnderBrace` commands from `nicematrix`. it appears to me, however, that it works only for `\UnderBrace`

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\highlightNodes}{ O { } }
{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{iRow}}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\arabic{jCol}}
    {
        \tikz [remember~picture, overlay] 
        \node [opacity=0.21] at (\i.5-|\j.5) {\color{gray} \i , \j} ;
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin, create-extra-nodes]
        \Block[fill=Coral3]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   &   0   \\
        & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
        &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
        0            &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
        \CodeAfter
        \highlightNodes
        \OverBrace[shorten]{1-1}{1-3}{C_{1}}
        \UnderBrace[shorten]{4-1}{4-3}{C_{3}}
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first and second argument of your command `\OverBrace` correspond to a sub-matrix of one row and three columns: the cells (1-1), (1-2) and (1-3). In the cells on both sides, there is no content and when the key `shorten` is in force, it tries to shorten according to the contents on the cells on both sides. Since there is nothing, `\OverBrace` does not shorten.

Maybe I will modify the behaviour to shorten according to the content of your cell `(1-2)`.

However, in your case, there is a possibility : `\OverBrace{1-1}{4-3}` will shorten according to the contents of the cells in the row 4.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\highlightNodes}{ O { } }
{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{iRow}}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\arabic{jCol}}
    {
        \tikz [remember~picture, overlay] 
        \node [opacity=0.21] at (\i.5-|\j.5) {\color{gray} \i , \j} ;
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin, create-extra-nodes]
        \Block[fill=Coral3]{3-3}<\large>{Z} & &   &   0   \\
          & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
          &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
        0 &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
        \CodeAfter
        \highlightNodes
        \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{1-1}{4-3}{C_{1}}
        \UnderBrace[shorten]{4-1}{4-3}{C_{3}}
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]